# Static linking of MySQL in C/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, static, linker

I am trying to develop an application that uses MySQL using C++. I downloaded the library from their website and I have attempted to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    mysql_init(&mysql);
}
```

The line that has `mysql_init(&mysql);` gives me a compilation error

```
undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
```

I am guessing this is due to a library error. I am linking `mysqlclient.lib` and `libmysql.lib` in that order. What do I need to do to make this compile without requiring a dll file? Is that possible? Thank you.
Note: I am using mingw32 on Windows 7 x64 to develop an application for Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this link will help. It states that mysqlclient.lib is the static library and libmysql.lib is the dynamic library, so I don't think you should be linking both.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/building-clients.html

Comment: It did, however after removing one of the two links I still receive the same error :(

Comment: Are you compiling your code for 64-bit but using a 32-bit version of the MySQL library to link it?

Comment: I am compiling 32 using 64bit libs. I got the 32 libs and I can only manage to compile the program when I use both `mysqlclient.lib` and `libmysql.lib` but then it won't launch without `libmysql.dll`, my goal is to make it statically linked. Any ideas?

Comment: I compiled and linked your program here and only needed the mysqlclient.lib library. I did also need to set the /MT option (Release) and the /MTd option (Debug). I used the 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Link to new documentation - there are some information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-building-clients.html I was able to compile static on Linux: https://github.com/SOCI/soci/issues/1131#issuecomment-2002503101